# Figcaption going to the right of a image instead of below

Tags: html, css

Recently I've decided to redesign my website and change the games list design but the figcaption that is suppose to be below the image decides to go to the right of it.

```css
.GameSelectList {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

figcaption {
    text-align: center;
    float: left
}

.GameSelectListLinkImg {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.GameSelectListLinkA {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="GameSelectList">
                <li class="GameSelectListLink"><a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/MinecraftClassic.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/MinecraftClassic.webp" alt="Minecraft" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a></li>
                <figcaption>Minecraft Classic</figcaption>
                <li class="GameSelectListLink"><a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/1v1lol.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/1v1.lol.jpg" alt="1v1.lol" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a></li>
                <figcaption>1v1.lol</figcaption>
                <li class="GameSelectListLink"><a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/FortBuilding.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/FortBuilding.jfif" alt="Fort Building" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a></li>
                <figcaption>Fort Building</figcaption>
                <li class="GameSelectListLink"><a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/GeoDash.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/GeometryDash.jfif" alt="Geometry Dash" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a></li>
                <figcaption>Geometry Dash</figcaption>
                <li class="GameSelectListLink"><a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/motothree.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/Motox3m.webp" alt="Moto X3m" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a></li>
                <figcaption>Moto X3M</figcaption>
                <li class="GameSelectListLink"><a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/tinyfishing.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/Tiny Fishing.webp" alt="Tiny Fishing" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a></li>
                <figcaption>Tiny Fishing</figcaption>
</ul>
```

Someone please help :) Also the indent on the HTML is not supposed to look like that in my code editor (VS Code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attain it using flex and grid. Do you mean like this?

```css
.GameSelectList {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

li.GameSelectListLin {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="GameSelectList">
                <li class="GameSelectListLink">
                <a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/MinecraftClassic.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/MinecraftClassic.webp" alt="Minecraft" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a>
                <figcaption>Minecraft Classic</figcaption>
                </li>
                
                <li class="GameSelectListLink">
                <a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/1v1lol.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/1v1.lol.jpg" alt="1v1.lol" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a>
                <figcaption>1v1.lol</figcaption>
                </li>
                
                <li class="GameSelectListLink">
                 
                <a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/FortBuilding.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/FortBuilding.jfif" alt="Fort Building" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a>
                <figcaption>Fort Building</figcaption>
                </li>
                
                <li class="GameSelectListLink">               
               <a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/GeoDash.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/GeometryDash.jfif" alt="Geometry Dash" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a>
               <figcaption>Geometry Dash</figcaption>
               </li>
                
                <li class="GameSelectListLink">               
                <a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/motothree.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/Motox3m.webp" alt="Moto X3m" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a>
                <figcaption>Moto X3M</figcaption>
                </li>
                
                <li class="GameSelectListLink">                
                <a class="GameSelectListLinkA" href="/Games/UnblockedGameFiles/tinyfishing.html"><img src="/Games/UnblockedGameImages/Tiny Fishing.webp" alt="Tiny Fishing" width="100" height="100" class="GameSelectListLinkImg"></a>
                <figcaption>Tiny Fishing</figcaption>
                </li>
                
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your html code problem is occuring in your css code just read it properly what you have written

```
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
    float: left
}
```

Just Remove `float:left` and the problem will be solved

Comment: No I think I forgot to mention but I want the images to be horizontal and the text beneath it

Answer (score 0):

use this structure

```
<figure>
        <img src="URL YOUR IMAGE" alt="">

        <figcaption>Minecraft Classic</figcaption>
</figure>
```

EDIT:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://astronautsdevelopers.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/capa-post-stackoverflow-survey-2020-1024x626.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>It's a link with image with figure tag</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I still want the image to be a button though :)

Comment: @Bentheminernz I didn't understand your question? your css is wrong. remove the styles, and use the ones just what I mentioned. In the update I made in my comment, I think it was clear what I mean